# retrieve hindi character from database

Tags: java, mysql

I have written a program which makes a search for the given hindi word in the mysql database and retrieves its corresponding name in english which is stored in the database.It works fine when i give the hindi word directly in the select statement but i would like to give it using a variable so it could be more general but i am not getting the result for the same..Could anyone help me with a solution to it..Thanks in adavance

This is the code which i have written

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] argv) {


    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {

        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

        }


    Connection connection = null;

                         SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
                                 dataSource.setServerName("COMP-PC");
                                dataSource.setPortNumber(1433);
                              dataSource.setDatabaseName("concept");
                              dataSource.setUser("root");
                            dataSource.setPassword("abc");

        try
         {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Connected to server !!!");
         Statement select = connection.createStatement();
         String var="N'हल्दी'";

     ResultSet result = select.executeQuery



               ("SELECT Name, Id FROM MConcept where CName=N'हल्दी'");  
     **// When given like the above statement it works fine 



                 ("SELECT Name, Id FROM MConcept where CName='"+var+" ' "); 
    **//This does not give result 


      System.out.println("Got results:");
      while(result.next()) { // process results one row at a time

      String Name = result.getString(1);
      int ID = result.getInt(2);

       System.out.println("name = " + Name);
       System.out.println("id = " + ID);
       }
      select.close();
     connection.close();
      }




  catch (SQLException e)
  {
   System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
   e.printStackTrace();
   return;
   }

    if (connection != null)
     {
    System.out.println("Successfully connected!");

     } 
   else 
    {
System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }


   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second statement is incorrect.

Should be

```
"SELECT Name, Id FROM MConcept where CName=" + var
```

But I highly suggest using PreparedStatement and read this cautionary tale of SQL injection -> http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

You have extra quotes; they're in both `var` and in your SQL.

Your working example is:

```
("SELECT Name, Id FROM MConcept where CName=N'हल्दी'");
```

While your broken example evaluates to:

```
("SELECT Name, Id FROM MConcept where CName='N'हल्दी' ' ");
```

Which presumably not only doesn't give a result, but should result in an error message about your SQL syntax since you have the string literal 'N' followed by unquoted Hindi characters in some encoding and a space in a new string.

It's also a very bad habit to build SQL by concatenating strings; make sure you never do this when the value is coming from user input rather than hardcoded like in your example.

Comment: I was able to store hindi value in the database when given like N'हल्दी'when i had given only the word हल्दी it was stored as ?????      my database looks like   Turmeric  हल्दी   1 where Turmeric is the name in english, हल्दी in hindi and 1 its Id..

Comment: Ya got the result you all were right there was a problem in the quotes..Thank you so much friends for all your help